# JS Scripts don't work in angular directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have file with directive

```js
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    function digest(factory) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/js/app/digest/templates/digest.template.html',
            scope: true,
            replace: true,
            controller: [
                '$scope', '$http',
                function ($scope, $http) {
....
                }
            ]
        };
        return directive;
    }

digest.$inject = ['digest.factory'];
    angular.module('news').directive('maindigest', digest);
})(angular);
```

Template

```js
<div>
<input id="datepicker"/>

<script>
      $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
</script>
</div>
```

Index.html is where that directive is defined

```js
<script src="/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/digest/digest.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/digest/digest.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app/digest/digest.factory.js"></script>

    <link href="/vendor/bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/vendor/bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/vendor/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<maindigest></maindigest>
...
// in here js scripts work
//<input id="datepicker"/>
//<script>
      //$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
//</script>
...
```

Could somebody help me, why some js scripts don't work into the template of directive.
my opinion is js functions is not exist in the template of directive, though in index.html is all right

Comment: This problem is likely occurring due to the fact that the input that you are trying to call your script on doesn't exist on the page during initialization, and therefore isn't known to your kendo script.  You need to research the documentation for kendoui to determine how to dynamically add new elements after the page has been loaded.  adding the kendoUi tag to your question may also help draw others who have dealt with the combination of angular and kendo to review your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add type=ng-template in your script tag.

Or maybe add kendo-date-picker attribute to your directive.

Comment: Could you give a some example please